# Actionscript memory management, garbage collection

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, memory-management, garbage-collection

[This blog](http://blogagic.com/163/flex-memory-management-and-memory-leaks#varref) (and others) state that you should set object references to null inside your dispose() methods when cleaning up objects.

However, Actionscript 3 (with Flash Player 9) uses [mark and sweep](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/garbage_collection.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_1) to clear out circular references for you. So I am wondering: is there really any reason to null out your object references?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I never do - as long as you do the obvious:

- Break all reference to the object (remove from arrays, set variables storing the object to null, remove from display list)
- Remove all event listeners and so on

Then the memory that was used by the object is available for overwriting at any time.

```
var ar:Array = [];
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pants);

ar[ar.length] = mc;
addChild(mc);

if(mc.parent) mc.parent.removeChild(mc); // not garbage collected
mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pants); // still not garbage collected
ar.splice(0, 1); // finally garbage collected
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it wouldn't be ready for gc unless it was removed from the display list. So maybe after ar.splice(0,1) in the example put removeChild(mc);

Comment: It is removed from the DisplayList..? Confused.

Comment: the garbage collector in AS3 uses a combination of reference counting and mark and sweep. mark and sweep is really *slow*. if you can free memory by nulling out your references, it's much quicker that to wait on the VM to kick in mark and sweep because it can't determine what's free or not.

Comment: Good info, I'll keep that in memory for future projects.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the MORE you can nullify all object references in your object, the more probable it is for the GC to sweep'em without having to dig very deep down the reference-chains of the objects. This is very important in order to keep your "garbage islands" significantly small in order to be collected. If you simply nullify 1 object reference and expect the remaining chunk of inter-referenced variables to get collected... it's possible the GC will give up on it (see http://bit.ly/jIuKrQ).

Answer (score 2):

A fantastic summary of memory management is the Grant Skinner presentation:

http://gskinner.com/talks/resource-management/

In summary though, I never `null` the objects themselves, but null the objects referencing them (there is a subtle but important difference). All references need to the object need to be destroyed though, and also event listeners, etc.

When adding event listeners, get into the habit of setting the listener to be `weak`.

`o.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick, false, 0, true);`

There is no disadvantage to this, and means that if you null all references to your object `o` but there is still listeners attached, they will remove themselves, and the object can still be marked for gc'ed. You should still handle your own removal of listeners regardless though.

> "don't get lazy - clean up after
>   yourself!"

Finally you can use the Janitor class to help monitor/clean up your resources:

http://gskinner.com/libraries/