# Garbage Collection in Adobe Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, garbage-collection, adobe

I've a question about garbage collection in flash.
I'm making a game using with Flash AS3. This game will stay open for a few hours, like 5 - 6 hours. People will play it again and again in these hours. I have 15 loader in my flash game and don't want to have a problem with Garbage Collection. I'm uninstalling every load object when it is not necessary but i'm not sure do i have trouble about this garbage collection?

If i do, how can i solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: We have no idea because you haven't described your actual memory management, nor posted any code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877674/actionscript-memory-management-garbage-collection/5877709#5877709

Comment: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/quick-tip-understanding-garbage-collection-in-as3/

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collection only collects garbage, that are objects that are no longer referenced. As such all objects you are still referencing will stay there, presumed that the Flash Player is able to keep the memory allocated.

It would be a better idea to make your application requiring less memory though.