# If I continually loop an Adobe Animate (Flash) video will it cause memory issues?

Tags: flash, video, actionscript, jquery-animate

In a kiosk executable I am building in Adobe Animate (Flash) I am using an FLVPlayback component as a video jukebox. Simple design: a looping home screen video, overlaid with buttons that swap the video source and then on their completion swap back in the home video.

My ActionScript for this loop includes a trace message:

```
video_viewer.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, videoSwitcher);
function videoSwitcher(e:Event)
{
  if (video_viewer.source == "video/Home.mp4") {
    trace("I'm Home and I'm looping!");         
  } else {
    trace(video_viewer.source + " is done so I'm switching to Home!");
    video_viewer.source = "video/Home.mp4";
  }
  video_viewer.seek(0);
  video_viewer.play();
}
```

My question is, if the home video loops hundreds or thousands of times a day while it is running at the client's tradeshow, will the repeated trace messages eventually cause memory issues?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran a brief test to be sure if Flash Player uses more memory over long run and repeated call of `trace()` function.

**Test Scenario:**
400 x 400 stage at 120 fps
Played a 5 minute video repeatedly and traced on every enter frame.

```
import flash.events.Event;

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,fps);
function fps(e){
    trace("A really long sentence to test whether trace eats up memory over time.");
}
```

**Note:** Video looping code was similar to the code mentioned in OP so not included in this answer.

1st Test within Adobe Animate by pressing `<Ctrl>+<Enter>` keyboard keys.
**Finding:** Kept on increasing memory usuage over long run (~54MB within 2 minutes).

2nd Test after publishing a swf with "*Omit trace statements*" disabled in publish settings.
**Finding:** Kept on increasing memory usuage over long run even though we cannot see trace output (~36MB within 2 minutes).

Final Test after publishing a swf with "*Omit trace statements*" enabled in publish settings.
**Finding:** Kept on increasing memory usuage reaching ~25MB usuage and then kept fluctuating between 25MB and 28MB, but never got higher than 28MB.

So, I conclude that we should enable "*Omit trace statements*" option in Publish Settings to prevent unintended memory leaks due to `trace()`. I assume, when it is disabled, `trace()` log is preserved for telemetry purpose.

**PS:** AVMs use garbage collectors (GC), so there can be other factors contributing in some objects not being GCed even after not being used, which can ultimately make your swf file more memory hogging. Check this post in order to learn more about memory management: [Actionscript memory management, garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877674/actionscript-memory-management-garbage-collection)